# Is collections.defaultdict thread-safe?

Tags: python, defaultdict, python-collections

I have not worked with threading in Python at all and asking this question as a complete stranger.

I am wondering if [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is thread-safe. Let me explain it:

I have

```
d = defaultdict(list)
```

which creates a list for missing keys by default. Let's say I have multiple threads started doing this at the same time:

```
d['key'].append('value')
```

At the end, I'm supposed to end up with `['value',  'value']`. However, if the `defaultdict` is not thread-safe, if the **thread 1** yields to **thread 2** after checking `if 'key' in dict` and before  `d['key'] = default_factory()`, it will cause interleaving, and the other thread will create list in `d['key']` and append `'value'` maybe.

Then when **thread 1** is executing again, it will continue from `d['key'] = default_factory()` which will destroy the existing list and value, and we will end up in `['key']`.

I looked at [CPython source code for defaultdict](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7272ef213b7c/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#l1484). However, I could not find any locks or mutexes. I guess it is not thread-safe as long as it is documented so.

Some guys last night on IRC said that there is GIL on Python, so it is conceptually thread-safe. Some said threading should not be done in Python. I'm pretty confused. Ideas?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/9ZnBQrYun1w may help

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is thread safe, *in this specific case*.

To know why it is important to understand when Python switches threads. CPython only allows switching between threads between Python bytecode steps. This is where the GIL comes in; every N byte code instructions the lock is released and a thread switch can take place.

The `d['key']` code is handled by one bytecode (`BINARY_SUBSCR`) that triggers the `.__getitem__()` method to be called on the dictionary.

A `defaultdict`, configured with `list` as the default value factory, and using string values as keys, handles the `dict.__getitem__()` method *entirely* in C, *and* the GIL is never unlocked, making `dict[key]` lookups thread safe.

Note the qualification there; if you create a `defaultdict` instance with a *different* default-value factory, one that uses Python code (`lambda: [1, 2, 3]` for example), all bets are off as that means the C code calls back into Python code and the GIL can be released again while executing the bytecode for the `lambda` function. The same applies to the keys, when using an object that implements either `__hash__` or `__eq__` in Python code then a thread switch can take place there. Next, if the factory is written in C code that explicitly releases the GIL, a thread switch can take place and thread safety is out the window.

Comment: Since it's [apparently] not in the documentation, this sounds like just a CPython implementation detail -- still useful to know, though.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that Python-written factories can trigger release of GIL. Unfortunately, it gets even hairier: GIL can potentially trigger on any `Py_DECREF` if the object is freed and has a `__del__`. This way even pure C code can unwittingly cause a release of the GIL — admittedly pathological, but it can happen.

Comment: Pretty interesting that developer should be aware of GIL releases between C/Python code execution back and forth. Thanks.

Comment: would this `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: False))` usage be thread safe since none of the dict values are list.

Comment: @darth_coder: that depends on the keys, because `hash(key)` can call out to Python if the key implements a Python `__hash__` or `__eq__` method.